# Is it possible to build VPN remote access environment without VPN server?

Tags: vpn

Is it possible to build VPN remote access environment without VPN server?

In this case, only VPN router on top of LAN is sufficient?

If not, why is the server needed in general?

Comment: what difference do you make between a VPN router and a VPN server?

Comment: voting to close as too broad, since we don't know anything about your VPN requirements (such as client OS, protocol preferences, etc...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VPN server` is a *function* (or a role) that can be builtin in a router software or installed on a more generic purpose operating system (linux, windows, etc...)

It is a matter of choice wether to use the VPN function that may be available on a router or to use another device to perform this role.

Since it is highly related to pure networking, and you usually want to configure some fire-walling on the traffic that goes through the connection, it makes sense to use a VPN-capable router that also provide advanced fire-walling and other security functions, but once again it is a choice, and there's no hard rule here.

Answer (score 1):

A VPN tunnel requires a *tunnel endpoint* or termination - where packets are encapsulated or extracted.

Whether you call that endpoint *server* or *router* or if it's integrated in some device doesn't matter, but you can't do without.

Answer (score 0):

Purely as a response to the title. You can setup a VPN without a sever if you'd setup a [SSH tunnel](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VPN_over_SSH). Second option would be using [wireguard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WireGuard) (experimental).

Both protocols have a more peer to peer nature than classic VPN and don't require you to install, secure and maintain a full blown VPN server.

Personaly I've used the SSH option quite a few times to jump over a firewall or connectivity to the home network.